ld can't find symbol, but lld can, why? (MinGW64 library on MSYS2)
On the MSYS2 shell, ld fails to link a simple binary:
$ clang++ -iquote /mingw64/include -L /mingw64/lib -lLLVM-16 -x c++ - <<<$'#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"\nint main() { llvm::errs(); }'
/mingw64/bin/ld: [...] undefined reference to `llvm::errs()'

However, if I use lld, then it works:
$ clang++ -fuse-ld=lld -iquote /mingw64/include -L /mingw64/lib -lLLVM-16 -x c++ - <<<$'#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"\nint main() { llvm::errs(); }'

Why is this?
(For reference, I'm using these precompiled libraries.)

Try putting -lLLVM-16 at the very end of the command (right before the <<< I guess).  The order of linkable objects matters.

@DavidGrayson: Oh geez, that fixed it, thanks. I didn't realize that the set of linkable objects whose ordering matters includes the object file produced from the source file itself... I guess this question is a duplicate then, thanks.

In this case, the order of .o and .a files was the culprit.
Reordering the files solved that issue.
HOWEVER: There can be another culprit too.
lld has another feature to aid DLL linking that ld has poor support for. It is supposed to support these via the following flags (which may be already enabled by default):
-Wl,--enable-auto-import,--enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc

However, they don't seem to quite work well, from what I find in practice.
If you get an error such as the following on a platform such as MinGW64...
ld: app.o:app.cpp:(.text+0x1000): undefined reference to `.refptr._ZN6symbol'

...then you may be running into this issue, and the only solution I see is to use lld -- nothing I did with ld managed to resolve these errors.
